# Suspend when lid is closed is not working (Lenovo v145-15AST) with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, 20.04

When I close the lid and open it again, nothing happens.

Things I've already done:

1. Installed pm-utils
2. Changed logind.conf
3. Tried on uef and legacy

Things I cannot do at the moment:
1. Upgrade Bios V2.02 to 8ZCN25WW(V2.04)

Note: I can suspend using power button or using command in terminal. When it was running Windows OS, this functionality was ok.

More informations below. I apretiate the help :)

```
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
[Login]
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

sergio@ventura:~$ lsb_release -a

```
sergio@ventura:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I can see these errors on boot.

```
sergio@ventura:~$ journalctl -b | grep Lid
May 15 19:30:57 ventura kernel: input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:24/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
May 15 19:30:57 ventura kernel: ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
May 15 19:30:57 ventura kernel: ACPI: More than one Lid device found!
May 15 19:31:36 ventura systemd-logind[1049]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
May 15 19:32:48 ventura /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2510]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)sergio@ventura:~$ journalctl -b | grep Error
May 15 19:30:57 ventura kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
May 15 19:31:24 ventura kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)I have already
```

tested with Ubuntu 18.04.3, 19.10, Linux Mint 18.3, 19.2, 19.3 and Kubuntu 18.04. I have the same error on Logs.Other system informations:

```
sergio@ventura:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for sergio: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: e2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:40 memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0800000-f0ffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f043ffff memory:c0000-dffff

sergio@ventura:~$ sergio@ventura:~$ dmesg | grep amd
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-29-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-035) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-29.33-generic 5.4.30)
[   20.262452] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   20.262671] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0xe8000000 -> 0xefffffff
[   20.262673] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xf0800000 -> 0xf0ffffff
[   20.262675] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0xf0400000 -> 0xf043ffff
[   20.262678] fb0: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA
[   20.262815] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   20.263452] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: kfd not supported on this ASIC
[   20.287543] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 80M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F404FFFFFF (80M used)
[   20.287545] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: GART: 1024M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF3FFFFFFF
[   20.287706] [drm] amdgpu: 80M of VRAM memory ready
[   20.287710] [drm] amdgpu: 2867M of GTT memory ready.
[   22.170342] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is smu8_smu
[   22.237446] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: bound 0000:00:01.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[   22.378943] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   22.379049] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[   22.405177] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.35.0 20150101 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0


sergio@ventura:~$ dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
[   20.262452] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   20.262671] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0xe8000000 -> 0xefffffff
[   20.262673] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xf0800000 -> 0xf0ffffff
[   20.262675] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0xf0400000 -> 0xf043ffff
[   20.262678] fb0: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA
[   20.262815] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   20.263452] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: kfd not supported on this ASIC
[   20.287543] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 80M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F404FFFFFF (80M used)
[   20.287545] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: GART: 1024M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF3FFFFFFF
[   20.287706] [drm] amdgpu: 80M of VRAM memory ready
[   20.287710] [drm] amdgpu: 2867M of GTT memory ready.
[   22.170342] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is smu8_smu
[   22.237446] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: bound 0000:00:01.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[   22.378943] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   22.379049] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[   22.405177] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.35.0 20150101 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
sergio@ventura:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment because I don't have enough reputation, so I will try to help in answer.
Do you have an external monitor?
I had the same problem because of external monitor, so what I did:
 1. Open "dconf editor"
 2. Type to search "lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor"
 3. Toggle off "use default value"
 4. Set custom value to True
 5. Open "Tweaks" -> General -> Toggle on "suspend when laptop lid is closed".
And it worked!
May be you will have to reboot to make it work.

Comment: @Dim1iug3r, yes, I have an external monitor witch I plugged in. In dconf-editor I found  two "lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor" (see below),  I toggled both on and I restarted the computer. 
```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugin/power/lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor
/com/canonical/unity/settings-daemon/plugin/power/lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor
```
The other change I made was in logind.conf (see below). Also 
restarted de pc with the same result: lid close doesn't work.

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```